# Need an analytic model for describing a region with fast transition of magnetic field from a constant value to zero

Tags: electromagnetism

I would like to describe analytically the electromagnetic fields in a region with the magnetic field changing rapidly from a constant value to zero. It's more or less like the fringe region of the an opposite pair of north and south poles of a magnet. Let's say the magnetic field has dominant $z$ direction and small $x$ direction components. It's exactly invariant with y and varying slowly with $z$, but drops almost abruptly from H0 to zero across $x = 0$ (in a narrow transition region). I think it's not difficult to imagine such a setting, but it seems not very easy to come up with elegant mathematical expressions to describe the fields here (at the same time being compatible with Maxwell's equations). I guess there should be something out there I could use for this, just couldn't find it. Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand your setup, but would $B_z = B_0(1 + \tanh(x/\alpha))$ do the trick, where $\alpha$ was some scale length? e.g. see below with $\alpha=1$. Or did you mean that it is the x-component of the field that drops abruptly with x?

[image: A plot of 1+tanh(x) generated with WolframAlpha]

Comment: You should have $\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0$, so I don't think your suggested magnetic field would qualify.

Comment: I should made it clear that this is the field in the z direction, let me have another go...

Comment: I think this function form might work. The expression should be possible to derive so that Gauss's law is satisfied.